# button on press being called before button press

Tags: python, button, event-handling, kivy, buttonclick

I am trying to add a set of buttons to a  grid layout scroll view using for loop. But the on press event is being triggered for all the buttons even before pressing the buttons. How can I fix this?

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
import webbrowser


def btnsclicked(id, url):
    print 'btn id '+id+' clicked'
    webbrowser.open(url)

layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

for i in range(5):
    url= 'https://www.google.com'
    btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40, id='b'+str(i))
    btn.bind(on_press =btnsclicked('b'+str(i), url))
    layout.add_widget(btn)
root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
root.add_widget(layout)

runTouchApp(root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are actually calling your callback when passing args:

```
btn.bind(on_press =btnsclicked('b'+str(i), url))
```

Doc example says:

```
def callback(instance):
    print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)
btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
btn1.bind(on_press=callback)
```

You have to pass a function (not a function call) accepting only 1 argument: instance of the activated widget.

do this using `lambda` expressions that define functions in-line:

```
btn.bind(on_press = lambda x : btnsclicked('b'+str(i), url))
```

When an event is triggered, the `on_press` callback is called with one argument: the widget id. That calls your `lambda` function which calls `btnsclicked` discarding this argument (that you don't need here), but passing your text id and the url you want to associate to.

Comment: hi Jean, how can I pass the arguments without calling the function?

Comment: by using lamba expression which is a relay function to connect the callback to your custom callback.

Answer (score 2):

For `on_press`, you call the function instead of specifying the function to use. Try:

```
btn.bind(on_press=lambda x: btnsclicked('b' + str(i), url))
```

If you want to deal with arguments, see [Event dispatcher](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html):

```
def btnsclicked(*args):
    id_, url = args
    print('btn id {} clicked'.format(id_))
    webbrowser.open(url)

btn.bind(on_press=btnsclicked)
```